# window form always on top

Tags: c#, winforms, messagebox

I have a part of cord that call out a window form. but not everytime will on top, sometime the window message box will behind the browser, I wonder is there anyway that can make it always on top? I have used bringtofront, but it is still not working. the code below is my code that call out the window form.

```
public void CreateMyForm()
        { 
            // Create a new instance of the form.
            System.Windows.Forms.Form form1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Form();
            // Create two buttons to use as the accept and cancel buttons.
            System.Windows.Forms.Button button1 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            System.Windows.Forms.Button button2 = new System.Windows.Forms.Button();
            System.Windows.Forms.Label lblMsg = new System.Windows.Forms.Label(); 

            form1.Size = new System.Drawing.Size(250,150);  

            lblMsg.BorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.BorderStyle.Fixed3D;
            lblMsg.ImageIndex = 1;
            lblMsg.ImageAlign = ContentAlignment.TopLeft;
            lblMsg.UseMnemonic = true;
            lblMsg.Text = "Are you sure? once save Status as CLOSED, this ticket detail cannot be change!";
            lblMsg.Size = new Size(lblMsg.PreferredWidth, lblMsg.PreferredHeight);
            form1.Text = "Are you sure? once save Status as CLOSED, this ticket detail cannot be change!";

            // Set the text of button1 to "OK".
            button1.Text = "OK";
            // Set the position of the button on the form.
            button1.Location = new Point(30, 70);
            // Set the text of button2 to "Cancel".
            button2.Text = "Cancel";
            // Set the position of the button based on the location of button1.
            button2.Location
               = new Point(button1.Left + button1.Width + 20, 70);
            // Make button1's dialog result OK.
            button1.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK;
            // Make button2's dialog result Cancel.
            button2.DialogResult = System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.Cancel;
            // Set the caption bar text of the form.   
            form1.Text = "My Dialog Box";

            // Define the border style of the form to a dialog box.
            form1.FormBorderStyle = System.Windows.Forms.FormBorderStyle.FixedDialog;
            // Set the accept button of the form to button1.
            form1.AcceptButton = button1;
            // Set the cancel button of the form to button2.
            form1.CancelButton = button2;
            // Set the start position of the form to the center of the screen.
            form1.StartPosition = System.Windows.Forms.FormStartPosition.CenterScreen;

            // Add button1 to the form.
            form1.Controls.Add(button1);
            // Add button2 to the form.
            form1.Controls.Add(button2);

            // Display the form as a modal dialog box.
            form1.BringToFront();
            form1.ShowDialog();

            // Determine if the OK button was clicked on the dialog box. 
            if (form1.DialogResult == System.Windows.Forms.DialogResult.OK)
            {
                // Display a message box indicating that the OK button was clicked.
                update();
                // Optional: Call the Dispose method when you are finished with the dialog box.
                form1.Dispose();
            }
            else
            { 
                // Optional: Call the Dispose method when you are finished with the dialog box.
                form1.Dispose();
            }
        }
```

The code below also a message box that show the erroe message, but it is also not always on top.

```
string errorMsg = "Error";
            if(DropDownListStatus.SelectedIndex == 4){
                System.Windows.Forms.MessageBox.Show(errorMsg, "window title", System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxButtons.OK, System.Windows.Forms.MessageBoxIcon.Warning);

            }
```

your comment and suggestion is much appreaciated!..Thank you

Comment: I fail to see why you would want to programatically create your own "OK/Cancel" dialoge, when you could have just used `MessageBox.Show()` with the appriopiate parameters. Also, are you setting the parent of your newly created window right? That might be why `BringToFront()` has no effect. Otherwise, you could still force the window to **always** be on top by setting the `TopMost` property of the form to `true`. (https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.form.topmost.aspx)

Comment: The reason why is because my system required to support multilingual, that is why I need to create the dialoge. hope you understand it.

Comment: Why did you tag this as ASP.NET?

Comment: Try calling `Activate();` and then `BringToFront();`

Answer (score 1):

You just have to set the [TopMost](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/vstudio/system.windows.forms.form.topmost(v=vs.100).aspx) property of the form to True

```
        // Display the form as a modal dialog box.
        form1.TopMost = True;
        form1.ShowDialog();
```

Topmost forms are always displayed at the highest point in the z-order of the windows on the desktop.

Comment: can I make it like the user need to click button on the window form first?

Answer (score 0):

To make the `MessageBox.Show` dialog topmost you could do something the following

```
MessageBox.Show(new Form { TopMost = true }, "I am Top Most!", "title", 
    MessageBoxButtons.OK, 
    MessageBoxIcon.Warning);
```

Obviously, `new Form { TopMost = true }` will create a new form instance for the messagebox with a TopMost setting to true. This will ensure that the MessageBox is displayed in front of all your other forms until you close it.